# Is it possible that, decentralized solution with mysql

Tags: mysql, distributed, mysql-cluster

Is it possible that decentralized mysql solution. Where updates in one mysql server has to reflect on all other regions. Like wise other region changes should sync with remaning regions.

Answer (score 1):

Some popular solutions are:

- Master/Slave replication. Easy to set up, but you have to change your code to write to the one master server, and to read from the many slave servers. It won't scale well when you get too many connections that the master itself will become busy.
- Master/Master replication. Can scale indefinitely, but the two master databases can have conflicting data, unlike the master/slave scenario. When that happens, you will also have to code somewhat complex solutions in your application to deal with the corrupt data. It is also possible to set a master that sends data to a slave that happens to be a master of another slave, binding all in a master/slave system that goes in circles.

  - Mysql Cluster. It performs master/master replication without corruption and auto sharding, giving you performance and scalability without the need to change code in your application. However, it is not as popular. You won't find tutorials online on how to set it up, you'll have to go through the official documentation, and any issues you have with it will be more difficult to find answers online as well.

  With any of these strategies, changes you make to one database are replicated to 1 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mysql Cluster solution
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/

Comment: Can I update, delete and insert records from  multiple mysql servers ?

Comment: This is what this solution is designed for. Yes